# hide div content in Dynamics CRM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamics-crm, crm

Following is the code I have done so far to hide a div content. But unfortunately it is not working on CRM online.

```
 function hideSocialEmailErrorMsgBlock() {
       debugger;
       var _errorMsgBlock = document.getElementById("emailnotification");
       var _warningMessage = document.getElementById("warningmessage");
       if ((errorMsgBlock == null && errorMsgBlock == undefined) || (warningMessage == null && warningMessage != undefined)) 
       {
        setTimeout(hideSocialEmailErrorMsgBlock, 1000);
        return;
       }
       else
       {
        document.getElementById("emailnotification").innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById("warningmessage").innerHTML = '';
        // code has to be placed here...
        // $("#warningmessage").hide();
        // $("warningmessage").attributes("style.display","none");
        // $("emailnotification").attributes("style.display","none");
        //$("#emailnotification").hide();
        setTimeout(hideSocialEmailErrorMsgBlock, 1000);
       }
    }
```

It is the image of front end.

[image]

Here is the image of web page.

[image]

I have to hide error showing on web page.

Comment: Do you want to hide it permanently ?

Comment: lets say yes, then?

Comment: You could hide it with CSS , `.emailnotification{ display : none !important;  }`

Comment: ok brother, If I want to do it on run time?

Comment: I cannot use CSS on CRM

Comment: upvote this MS idea: https://ideas.dynamics.com/ideas/dynamics-crm/2721751

Answer (score 1):

If you want to completely hide your emailnotification div with `Javascript`, you can just use:

> document.getElementById('emailnotification').style.display = 'none';

This would be a simpler alternative than trying to hide all of the text.

Comment: or you can try with jquery with .hide() function.